# How to ask a person whether his old question is still needs to be answered by me?

Tags: american-english, british-english, questions, figures-of-speech

A person msg me a week ago with a question. How should I ask him whether the question is still needs to be answered?

Is your question still actual for you? 
Is this question still valid?
Is your question still a current matter?

Etc

Thanks!

Comment: *Do you still need an answer?*

Comment: You could simply ask: _Do you still need an answer to your question?_ But beware of the word _actual_. It is a 'false friend' (cf. _aktuell_ in German) and does not mean _current_.